# Android file writing Read-Only file system warning

Tags: android, android-file

I'm trying to write a file using the `FileOutputStream`and `OutputStreamWriter`but I keep getting a read only warning.

Here is the code that I am using

```
FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream((trackName.replaceAll(" ", ""))+".gpx", true);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fw);
    osw.write(XML_HEADER+"\n");
    osw.write(TAG_GPX+"\n");


    writeTrackPoints(trackName, osw, locations, time, trackDescp);
    writeWayPoints(osw, locations,time);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
```

And the `Logcat`output is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /test.gpx (Read-only file system)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:168)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:147)
at com.fyp.run_race.GPXFileWriter.<init>(GPXFileWriter.java:25)
at com.fyp.run_race.GPSTrackDetails$1.onClick(GPSTrackDetails.java:58)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I ament sure what the problem is really.

Comment: Do you set user-permission for this in Android Manifest ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write files only to Internal Storage (device memory) or External Storage (the SD card), see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. Simply opening a FileOutputStream with an arbitrary file name won't work since that file system is read-only.

Answer (score 10):

Dunno why Pratik's comment was downvoted -- he's right in that you'll want the permission to write to external storage. Assuming that's where you want to write.

Devconsole is also right; you can't just write to any arbitrary filename, most of the file system is locked down and read-only.

To write to an arbitrary location in external storage (sdcard), use [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) for the root of external storage. Also use [getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29) to confirm that external storage is actually available.

Don't place files in the root of external storage; place them in a subdirectory to prevent the root from becoming too cluttered. (Edit: and some Android implementations won't let you do this anyway.)

Use [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) to get a location in external storage that's nominally private to your application. (New in API 8)

Use [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) to get a location under /data/ where you can write application-private files. This isn't on external storage, so space is tight; don't write big files here.

See also:

- getDir() -- Get a directory under /data/data/*yourapname*/
- getFilesDir() -- Return the directory /data/data/*yourappname*/files/
- fileList() -- List the files in /data/data/*yourappname*/files/
- getFileStreamPath() -- Get a file in /data/data/*yourappname*/files/
- openFileInput() -- Opens a file from within /data/data/*yourappname*/files/ for reading
- openFileOutput() -- Opens a file from within /data/data/*yourappname*/files/ for writing
- getCacheDir() -- Return the directory /data/data/*yourappname*/cache/
- getExternalCacheDir() -- Return the directory /sdcard/Android/data/*yourappname*/cache/
- deleteFile()

Answer (score 3):

just give permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```